# for loop 1 to 1 in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have issue with for loop:

```
for file in "$list"
        do
            if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
                final_list="$final_list $file"
            fi
        done
```

In $list is stored something file file1 file2 file3 and I need to check each word if exist file with that name. It works well if I have in $list more than one word. But if $list containst just one word it don't work. Variable $final_list is empty.

Thank you

Comment: You have other problems. It will work fine with a single file in `$list`. Double-check that when you think there is only 1 file in `$list` there is actually 1 file in `$list`. e.g. `list=dog; for i in $list; do echo $i; done` works fine.

Comment: Don't use a string as a list, use a bash array. If your file names are actually `file1`, `file2` etc. you could do `final_list=( file? )`. You should probably enable `nullglob` with `shopt -s nullglob` so you don't end up with an array containing `file?` in case no files exist.

Comment: Replace `"$list"` by  `$list`.

Comment: You also know you are checking **if $file does NOT exist** ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you!!! spend 2 hours on it

Comment: Glad I could help, some times it is the little things like that we can stare at for hours and never see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with double quotes. They prevent word-splitting on $list, so $file contains the whole $list.

But, as the condition checks for non-existence, single file woudl failt the condition, but for a list like `'file1 file2'`, as file of that name doesn't exist, the whole list is assigned to $final_list.

Try running the script with `set -xv` to see what's going on.